# configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile

Tags: gcc, makefile, compiler-errors, arm, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I am trying to compile a compiler for ARM targets using as base following link:

https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/arm-none-eabi-gcc/-/blob/main/PKGBUILD?ref_type=heads

I have installed the dependencies following the site:

https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html

gmp-6.2.1
mpfr-4.1.0
mpc-1.2.1
isl-0.24

but I have these errors, Please help

configure error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile

```
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/libcc1'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/libcc1'
Checking multilib configuration for libgcc...
mkdir -p -- arm-none-eabi/libgcc
Configuring in arm-none-eabi/libgcc
configure: creating cache ./config.cache
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-none-eabi
checking for --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for arm-none-eabi-ar... arm-none-eabi-ar
checking for arm-none-eabi-lipo... arm-none-eabi-lipo
checking for arm-none-eabi-nm... /home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/nm
checking for arm-none-eabi-ranlib... arm-none-eabi-ranlib
checking for arm-none-eabi-strip... arm-none-eabi-strip
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for arm-none-eabi-gcc... /home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/ -B/arm-none-eabi/bin/ -B/arm-none-eabi/lib/ -isystem /arm-none-eabi/include -isystem /arm-none-eabi/sys-include   
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/arm-none-eabi/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details
make[1]: *** [Makefile:13195: configure-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build'
make: *** [Makefile:1035: all] Error 2
```

```
CFLAGS=${CFLAGS/-Werror=format-security/}
CXXFLAGS=${CXXFLAGS/-Werror=format-security/}

export CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET='-g -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections'
export CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET='-g -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections'

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/gmp/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mpfr/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mpc/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/isl/lib

_target=arm-none-eabi

../gcc/configure \
    --target=$_target \
    --prefix= \
    --with-sysroot=/$_target \
    --with-native-system-header-dir=/include \
    --libexecdir=/usr/lib \
    --enable-languages=c,c++ \
    --enable-plugins \
    --disable-decimal-float \
    --disable-libffi \
    --disable-libgomp \
    --disable-libmudflap \
    --disable-libquadmath \
    --disable-libssp \
    --disable-libstdcxx-pch \
    --disable-nls \
    --disable-shared \
    --disable-threads \
    --disable-tls \
    --with-gnu-as \
    --with-gnu-ld \
    --with-system-zlib \
    --with-newlib \
    --with-headers=/$_target/include \
    --with-python-dir=share/gcc-arm-none-eabi \
    --with-gmp=/usr/local/gmp \
    --with-mpfr=/usr/local/mpfr \
    --with-mpc=/usr/local/mpc \
    --with-isl=/usr/local/isl \
    --with-libelf \
    --enable-gnu-indirect-function \
    --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' \
    --with-pkgversion='Arch Repository' \
    --with-bugurl='https://bugs.archlinux.org/' \
    --with-multilib-list=rmprofile


make INHIBIT_LIBC_CFLAGS='-DUSE_TM_CLONE_REGISTRY=0'
```

```
here the log file

This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by GNU C Runtime Library configure 1.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ /home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/gcc/libgcc/configure --srcdir=../../../gcc/libgcc --cache-file=./config.cache --enable-multilib --with-cross-host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix= --with-sysroot=/arm-none-eabi --with-native-system-header-dir=/include --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-plugins --disable-decimal-float --disable-libffi --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-threads --disable-tls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-system-zlib --with-newlib --with-headers=/arm-none-eabi/include --with-python-dir=share/gcc-arm-none-eabi --with-libelf --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-host-libstdcxx=-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm --with-pkgversion=Arch Repository --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-multilib-list=rmprofile --enable-languages=c,c++,lto --program-transform-name=s&^&arm-none-eabi-& --disable-option-checking --with-target-subdir=arm-none-eabi --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-none-eabi --target=arm-none-eabi

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = ultron
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.15.0-86-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #96-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 20 08:23:49 UTC 2023

/usr/bin/uname -p = x86_64
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2083: creating cache ./config.cache
configure:2295: checking build system type
configure:2309: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2329: checking host system type
configure:2342: result: arm-none-eabi
configure:2448: checking for --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs
configure:2461: result: no
configure:2532: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2600: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2616: checking for gawk
configure:2643: result: gawk
configure:2766: checking for arm-none-eabi-ar
configure:2793: result: arm-none-eabi-ar
configure:2858: checking for arm-none-eabi-lipo
configure:2885: result: arm-none-eabi-lipo
configure:2950: checking for arm-none-eabi-nm
configure:2977: result: /home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/nm
configure:3042: checking for arm-none-eabi-ranlib
configure:3069: result: arm-none-eabi-ranlib
configure:3134: checking for arm-none-eabi-strip
configure:3161: result: arm-none-eabi-strip
configure:3223: checking whether ln -s works
configure:3227: result: yes
configure:3244: checking for arm-none-eabi-gcc
configure:3271: result: /home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/ -B/arm-none-eabi/bin/ -B/arm-none-eabi/lib/ -isystem /arm-none-eabi/include -isystem /arm-none-eabi/sys-include   
configure:3540: checking for C compiler version
configure:3549: /home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/ -B/arm-none-eabi/bin/ -B/arm-none-eabi/lib/ -isystem /arm-none-eabi/include -isystem /arm-none-eabi/sys-include    --version >&5
xgcc (Arch Repository) 13.1.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3560: $? = 0
configure:3549: /home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/ -B/arm-none-eabi/bin/ -B/arm-none-eabi/lib/ -isystem /arm-none-eabi/include -isystem /arm-none-eabi/sys-include    -v >&5
Reading specs from /home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/specs
COLLECT_GCC=/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/xgcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-none-eabi
Configured with: ../gcc/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix= --with-sysroot=/arm-none-eabi --with-native-system-header-dir=/include --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-plugins --disable-decimal-float --disable-libffi --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-threads --disable-tls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-system-zlib --with-newlib --with-headers=/arm-none-eabi/include --with-python-dir=share/gcc-arm-none-eabi --with-gmp=/usr/local/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/mpc --with-isl=/usr/local/isl --with-libelf --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-pkgversion='Arch Repository' --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-multilib-list=rmprofile
Thread model: single
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 13.1.0 (Arch Repository) 
configure:3560: $? = 0
configure:3549: /home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/ -B/arm-none-eabi/bin/ -B/arm-none-eabi/lib/ -isystem /arm-none-eabi/include -isystem /arm-none-eabi/sys-include    -V >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-V'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3560: $? = 1
configure:3549: /home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/ -B/arm-none-eabi/bin/ -B/arm-none-eabi/lib/ -isystem /arm-none-eabi/include -isystem /arm-none-eabi/sys-include    -qversion >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3560: $? = 1
configure:3576: /home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/ -B/arm-none-eabi/bin/ -B/arm-none-eabi/lib/ -isystem /arm-none-eabi/include -isystem /arm-none-eabi/sys-include    -o conftest -g -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections   conftest.c  >&5
conftest.c:9:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <stdio.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
configure:3579: $? = 1
configure:3792: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3814: /home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/ -B/arm-none-eabi/bin/ -B/arm-none-eabi/lib/ -isystem /arm-none-eabi/include -isystem /arm-none-eabi/sys-include    -c -g -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  conftest.c >&5
/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/as: 114: exec: -march=armv4t: not found
configure:3818: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Runtime Library"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libgcc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Runtime Library 1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3832: error: in `/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/arm-none-eabi/libgcc':
configure:3834: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value='/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/ -B/arm-none-eabi/bin/ -B/arm-none-eabi/lib/ -isystem /arm-none-eabi/include -isystem /arm-none-eabi/sys-include   '
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-g -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=arm-none-eabi
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=arm-none-eabi
ac_cv_host=arm-none-eabi
ac_cv_prog_AR=arm-none-eabi-ar
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_CC='/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/ -B/arm-none-eabi/bin/ -B/arm-none-eabi/lib/ -isystem /arm-none-eabi/include -isystem /arm-none-eabi/sys-include   '
ac_cv_prog_LIPO=arm-none-eabi-lipo
ac_cv_prog_NM=/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/nm
ac_cv_prog_RANLIB=arm-none-eabi-ranlib
ac_cv_prog_STRIP=arm-none-eabi-strip

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR='arm-none-eabi-ar'
AWK='gawk'
CC='/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/ -B/arm-none-eabi/bin/ -B/arm-none-eabi/lib/ -isystem /arm-none-eabi/include -isystem /arm-none-eabi/sys-include   '
CET_FLAGS=''
CFLAGS='-g -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA='/usr/bin/install -c -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='/usr/bin/install -c'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='/usr/bin/install -c'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIPO='arm-none-eabi-lipo'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT='#'
NM='/home/users/truiz/projects/rtos_compiler/build/./gcc/nm'
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='GNU C Runtime Library'
PACKAGE_STRING='GNU C Runtime Library 1.0'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='libgcc'
PACKAGE_URL='http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.0'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PICFLAG='-fPIC'
RANLIB='arm-none-eabi-ranlib'
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP='arm-none-eabi-strip'
ac_ct_CC=''
accel_dir_suffix=''
asm_hidden_op=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_libsubdir='build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_subdir='build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
cpu_type=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
decimal_float=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
double_type_size=''
dvidir='${docdir}'
enable_decimal_float='no'
enable_execute_stack=''
enable_gcov='yes'
enable_shared='no'
enable_vtable_verify='no'
exec_prefix='NONE'
extra_parts=''
fixed_point=''
force_explicit_eh_registry=''
get_gcc_base_ver=''
host='arm-none-eabi'
host_alias='arm-none-eabi'
host_cpu='arm'
host_noncanonical='arm-none-eabi'
host_os='eabi'
host_subdir='.'
host_vendor='none'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='/usr/lib'
libgcc_topdir='../../../gcc/libgcc/..'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
long_double_type_size=''
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
md_unwind_header=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix=''
program_transform_name='s&^&arm-none-eabi-&'
psdir='${docdir}'
real_host_noncanonical=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
set_have_cc_tls=''
set_use_emutls=''
sfp_machine_header=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
slibdir='$(exec_prefix)/$(host_noncanonical)/lib'
solaris_ld_v2_maps=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias='arm-none-eabi'
target_noncanonical='arm-none-eabi'
target_subdir='arm-none-eabi'
thread_header=''
tm_defines=''
tm_file=''
tmake_file=''
toolexecdir='$(exec_prefix)/$(target_noncanonical)'
toolexeclibdir='$(toolexecdir)/lib'
unwind_header=''
use_tm_clone_registry=''
vis_hide=''
with_aix_soname='aix'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Runtime Library"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libgcc"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Runtime Library 1.0"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/"

configure: exit 1
```

Comment: *See `config.log' for more details*; what does it say. You need to scroll back from the dump of environment variables.  It will be helpful.

Comment: You appear to be trying to cross compile, which is appropriate. You have configured with the `--target` option, which is appropriate when you are *building* a cross-compiler, which you are not, but it's probably still ok provided that you specify the same host type that you are building for.  But you don't appear to be doing that.  In particular, you don't appear to have specified a `--host` triplet at all, and *that* is what engages cross-compilation.  `configure` behaves differently when you're cross-compiling.

Comment: The `conftest.c:9:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory` hints towards basic configuration missing or pointing to the wrong location.

Comment: many thanks for the answers, I didn't realize that I had to compile binutils+newlib+c compiler to generate the c++ compiler arm-none-eabi until I found this that worked fine https://gist.github.com/badcf00d/2f6054441375d9c94896aaa8e878ab4f